# Redis circular set in python?

Tags: python, redis, set, circular-buffer, circular-list

I have several workers written in python that are parsing pages and harvesting links. I'm trying to work out a way they can coordinate so they're not repeatedly hitting the same locations.

I'm thinking I can do this with redis. I'm trying to build a circular queue of an arbitrary size (say 10000 items) of a set type so that I can use sismember to verify a link has NOT been visited recently before parsing it (and not have to worry about entering the same link twice). I'm already doing this in memory with python set but this only works for a specific worker.

Is this possible? The other possibility I saw was building a set of unspecified size with timeouts attached to the individual members. I've only recently started using Redis so I am unsure if either of these are possible.

Comment: Take a look at http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache, you can limit the maximum amount of memory that redis uses with the `MaxMemory` config

Comment: I think I found a good workaround. I'm creating a key with the host name I want to set a time limit on and then checking for the keys existence before actually making a call. Still need to test with multiple workers but it looks like it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

thepirat000 gave a good response that he hasn't added as an answer. One way to do this is the add a memory limit onto redis so that the oldest data is evicted. The procedure for setting this up is documented on redis's site here: http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

In my specific use case I did something different, for page I parsed out the domain name and put a key generated using this information with arbitrary data into redis with a timeout associated with it. Each worker would then check for this key before attempting to parse any pages on that particular site.